# Bot should message two people when a command is ran

Tags: python, bots, discord

I'm making a discord bot. I wish to make the bot message myself, and my friend. I do have the message part where it replies to the person who executes the command, however I have no idea how to make it message people. Here's the code for the command I have so far. I've seen multiple versions of this question in other languages, however I do not know how to convert them to python.
Any help?

```
@UGH.command()
async def support():
   message = 'A Staff member will be with you shortly, please do not run this command more than once.'
   await UGH.say(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can message people for example with:

```
private_channel = await client.start_private_message(message.author)
await client.send_message(private_channel, "Message")
```